# Apex and preventing certain fields from carrying over during lead conversion?

Tags: apex, lead-conversion

Is there a way via Apex or other to prevent a custom field from being carried over from the Lead to the Account during lead conversion despite the field being explicitly mapped?

95% of the time, we want whatever fields we have mapped from Leads to Accounts to carry over when a Lead is converted.

Is there a way via Apex to prevent a certain custom field from carrying over during lead conversion using Apex or some other method?  So if Lead meets certain criteria, they get converted, but one of the fields that typically carries over just would not in this example.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a future method to overwrite the values back to how they were, or write a custom lead conversion page and overwrite the values after calling Database.convertLead. There's no way to just directly prevent the mapping from occurring.